# Custom date format in FastAPI model

Tags: python, date, datetime, fastapi, pydantic

I have a date type of the format `15-Jul-1996`. And I am trying to define a Pydantic model to use for input data validation in a FastAPI application as such:

```py
from pydantic import BaseModel
from datetime import date

class Profile(BaseModel):
    name: str
    DOB: date  # type of 15-Jul-1996
    gender: str
```

Is there a way to constrain the `DOB` to that particular format? I can't seem to find a way to do that in the Pydantic docs.

The attempt above is not quite what I want as it constrains to `05-07-2023`.

Comment: A date object does not _have_ a format per se. It is just a structure with fields for the number of years, months and days. What you describe is a **string representation** of a date. So the question is _where_ do you want to see/use this specific date format. When you dump your model object to JSON? When you `print` it to stdout? Since you tagged FastAPI I assume this model is either for a request or response body schema. Please explain what do you want to do with this model and where you need this date format.

Comment: I would probably want to display "date" type in the swagger UI but from @suraj sharma's answer, it would show up as str. Which is okay I guess for my use case. Also, I would like to constrain the format when the user passes the data to my endpoint. And throw a validation error if it's not in that format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this. You can use @validator

```
from pydantic import BaseModel, validator
from datetime import datetime

class Profile(BaseModel):
    name: str
    DOB: str  # change this to str
    gender: str

    @validator('DOB')
    def parse_dob(cls, v):
        return datetime.strptime(v, '%d-%b-%Y').date()  # convert string to date
```

Comment: This is not a good solution because you define the type of `DOB` to be `str`, yet assign a `date` object to that field in the validator and thus destroy type safety. You should at least leave `DOB: date` and make this a `pre=True` validator.

Comment: provide the other solution @DaniilFajnberg . I shared the best of my knowledge. It might not be the best solution.

Comment: I did not downvote, just felt the need to point this out. Your code still technically solves the parsing problem, so it is not wrong per se. I just think type safety is important and one of the main purposes of Pydantic in the first place, which is why declaring a field of one type, but assigning it a different type rubs me the wrong way. I provided my suggested solution in a separate answer in case you are interested.

Answer (score 2):

If you want the model to still hold an actual `date` object in that field, you should definitely leave the annotate as `date_of_birth: date` rather than simply switching to `str`.

If you want to allow strings with a particular format to be passed as a special case, you should define a [`pre=True` validator](https://docs.pydantic.dev/1.10/usage/validators/#pre-and-per-item-validators) that will check for strings and attempt to parse those accordingly. This is similar to [@suraj's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76617070/19770795), but has the advantage of type safety.

For even more clarity, you could set your desired date format as a [class variable](https://docs.pydantic.dev/1.10/usage/models/#automatically-excluded-attributes) on the module.

For the API, you could leverage the fact that the JSON Schema specs allow the [`format` keyword](https://json-schema.org/understanding-json-schema/reference/string.html#format) for `string` types with custom format specifications. You could [extend the automatically generated schema](https://docs.pydantic.dev/1.10/usage/schema/#schema-customization) for the model to display for example that same date format for every `date` type field in the model instead of just showing the standard format called `"date"`. Note that there is no special type for dates in JSON, so the Swagger UI would always have to show that field as `string` regardless.

Lastly, to make it crystal clear for users of the API what that format represents, you could add an example data object to the schema at the end.

Here is the full code I suggest:

```py
from __future__ import annotations
from datetime import date, datetime
from typing import Any, ClassVar

from pydantic import BaseModel, validator


class Profile(BaseModel):
    date_format: ClassVar[str] = "%d-%b-%Y"
    example_data: ClassVar[dict[str, Any]] = {
        "name": "John Doe",
        "date_of_birth": "15-Jul-1996",
        "gender": "m",
    }

    name: str
    date_of_birth: date
    gender: str

    @validator("date_of_birth", pre=True)
    def string_to_date(cls, v: object) -> object:
        if isinstance(v, str):
            return datetime.strptime(v, cls.date_format).date()
        return v

    class Config:
        @staticmethod
        def schema_extra(schema: dict[str, Any], model: type[Profile]) -> None:
            for name, field in model.__fields__.items():
                if field.type_ is date:
                    schema["properties"][name]["format"] = model.date_format
            schema["examples"] = [model.example_data]
```

Demo:

```py
profile_example = Profile.parse_obj(Profile.example_data)
print(profile_example.json(indent=4))
print(Profile.schema_json(indent=4))
```

Output:

```json
{
    "name": "John Doe",
    "date_of_birth": "1996-07-15",
    "gender": "m"
}
```

```json
{
    "title": "Profile",
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
        "name": {
            "title": "Name",
            "type": "string"
        },
        "date_of_birth": {
            "title": "Date Of Birth",
            "type": "string",
            "format": "%d-%b-%Y"
        },
        "gender": {
            "title": "Gender",
            "type": "string"
        }
    },
    "required": [
        "name",
        "date_of_birth",
        "gender"
    ],
    "examples": [
        {
            "name": "John Doe",
            "date_of_birth": "15-Jul-1996",
            "gender": "m"
        }
    ]
}
```

Even if you don't want to go the extra mile with the schema customization, I would still argue for using the proper field type and pre-validating strings instead.

Here is the minimal version:

```py
from datetime import date, datetime

from pydantic import BaseModel, validator


class Profile(BaseModel):
    name: str
    date_of_birth: date
    gender: str

    @validator("date_of_birth", pre=True)
    def string_to_date(cls, v: object) -> object:
        if isinstance(v, str):
            return datetime.strptime(v, "%d-%b-%Y").date()
        return v
```

The disadvantage is that the `format` default shown in the JSON Schema is `date`, which has a different meaning and is equivalent to `%d-%m-%Y`, which obviously does not fit your actual requirements. But parsing would still work of course with that validator.